# I am getting expr syntax errors for a simple equations

Tags: expr

here is the code:

```
lidarachynska@MacBook-Air-Lida ~ % cd rachynska
lidarachynska@MacBook-Air-Lida rachynska % vim bin/com2
lidarachynska@MacBook-Air-Lida rachynska % chmod a+x bin/com2
lidarachynska@MacBook-Air-Lida rachynska % PATH=$PATH:~/rachynska/bin
lidarachynska@MacBook-Air-Lida rachynska % com2
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
```

I've tried two ways of writing expr in com2, but both of them didn't work

No1

```
a=`expr $3`
b=`expr $2 - $1`
c=`expr $2 + $1`
d=`expr $b \* $c`
a=`expr $d / 7`
echo $a
```

No2

```
a=$(expr $3)
b=$(expr $2 - $1)
c=$(expr $2 + $1)
d=$(expr $b \* $c)
a=$(expr $d / 7)
echo $a
```

Comment: You don't pass any parameters to com2 so the variables are all empty  so you are calling expr with no values.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thanks! but I tried com2 0 2 4 5 and got only
0